# How do I write a playbook which gives me an option to choose between config and iteractive mode

Tags: ansible

I am writing a playbook which takes input from user and process that input.
Also I can use same inputs from config file. Now, How do I modify playbook such that I should be able to select interactive mode and take input from command line or select **config** to use same values from configuration file?

Analogy: We use switch statements in programming languages, Based on input option code execution takes different path.
Do we have similar concept in ansible?

Comment: Since Ansible is a [Configuration Management](https://www.ansible.com/use-cases/configuration-management) tool and was not designed to be a programming language, there is not really such concept. However, it could be possible to implement such behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Prompts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html) can be used to get the user input and [vars_files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#included-variables) to set the default values in a file.

```yaml
- name: Prompt & defaults
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - defaults.yml
  vars_prompt:
    - name: username
      prompt: What is the username? Leave it empty to get the default value
      default: "{{ default_username }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Print a message
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ username }}"
```

defaults.yml

```yaml
default_username: username_from_vars
```

The default value would be shown between square brackets:

```yaml
What is the username? Leave it empty to get the default value [username_from_vars]:
```